# Scroll and get the element using jquery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I am new to javascript and jquery. I am using a walkMe tool to give User instructions for the UI. I wanted to select one element through jquery using.

```
p:contains("Help")
```

This works if this 'Help' option is currently visible on the page but if this tag is not visible and required scrolling then this gives error that element is not present on the screen.

Is there any query which will check this elements on entire page or scroll till this element is found.

I want a one liner jquery to select this element on entire page or scroll till this element is found as I cant write a function in this tool.

Comment: Did you succeed at your code?

Answer (score 0):

To scroll to an element in JQuery, you can use something like this:

```
$('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: $("#ID_OF_ELEMENT").offset().top
}, 1000);
```

Where 1000 is the time in miliseconds to finish the animation. This code is going to get you to the top of the element.

Comment: Id is created dynamically. I can get that particular element with p:contains("Help")